# Fill material table with data from API using angular DataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an api which send data from backend, so when I try to get this data in my angular the data is not loaded in the first time, and my table stay empty, but if for example print the data that come from banckend before setting it in my DataSource, my table is fill correctly.

My code is:

**user-datasource.ts**

```
export class UserListDataSource extends DataSource<User> {
  data: User[];
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    this.data = this.usersService.usersList();
    //this.data.forEach(u => console.log(u.id)); <<---------- When I log this, My data is fill corectly
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }
  ...
```

}

**userService**

```
export class UsersService {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  usersList() {    
    this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`).pipe(
      map((jsonArray: Object[]) =>  jsonArray.map(jsonItem => User.fromJson(jsonItem)))
    ).subscribe((users: User[]) => { this.users = users; });

    return this.users;
  }

}
```

**component**

```
export class UserListComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<User>;

  dataSource: UserListDataSource = new UserListDataSource(this.usersService);

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'email', 'username'];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

---

I'm not sure if I use the correct way to fill my table, or I miss something.

From what I see, I think the backend took a long time than the frontend to load data, in another word, frontend is not waiting the necessary time to get data from backend.

Is there any way to fix this please?

---

**Note:** I use angular material schematics to create all this, in the default code, it use a static data, which is not the solution for me, which I need to use dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should await for the server response before you send the users collections back.

UsersService

```
usersList(): Observable<User[]> {    
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`).pipe(
      map((jsonArray: Object[]) =>  jsonArray.map(jsonItem => User.fromJson(jsonItem)))
    );
}
```

UserService just returns the promise of the user's collection.
In your `UserListComponent`, create a `MatTableDataSource` of type `User` and await the data from the your service. Then, once it is fulfilled, add that data to the `datasource`.

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private users: User[] = [];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  columns: string[] = ['...'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private service: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.usersList().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.dataSource.data = this.users;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

And, the last point. Use the `dataSource` input from the `table` tag to bind your `MatTableDataSource` to the table.

```
<table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this work very well with me, so from your solution I don't need to `UserListDataSource`?

Comment: Well, if you are not implement anything really tricky, there is no need to extend from DataSource. MatTableDataSource<TData> does this for you, indeed.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but is there any trick to stick with `DataSource`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry, hehe. Could you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly the problem is but I recently wrote a couple tables with angular material. Here is the simple way that I used to connect with a table.

```
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

constructor (
    private userSettingsService: UserSettingsService) 
{
    super();
}

  public usersDataStream = new BehaviorSubject<IUser[]>([]);

  connect(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    return this.usersDataStream.asObservable();
  }
  disconnect() {
    this.usersDataStream.complete();
  }
}
```

And then in the component class:

```
public dataSource: UserDataSource;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this._userSettingsService);
}
```

and then the HTML template:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
</mat-table>
```